# Alternative to DecimalFormat in Android

Tags: java, android, oop, sdk, android-version

I'm trying to make a method that receives a double and returns a String formatted with always 2 numbers after the decimal point.

For example:

1990.999 -> "1990.99"

1990.9 -> "1990.90"

I'm developing an app using Android min sdk version 21, so I can't use DecimalFormat. I manage to make something that works like this:

```
public String currencyFormat(double value) {
        return value < 0
                ? String.format("-" + currencySymbol + "%.02f", value * -1)
                : String.format(currencySymbol + "%.02f", value);
    }
```

However, the problem here is that if I try for example 1999,369 the result is "1999,37". Is there a way to prevent the round out?

Comment: Can you use `Formatter`?

Comment: what if you have an int `99` without any point? should be `99.00` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this method instead:

```
public static String currencyFormat(double value) {
    value = Math.floor(value * 100) / 100; // rounds 'value' to 2 decimal places
    return String.format("%.2f", value); // converts 'value' to string
}
```

Comment: It still round out the value.

Comment: @JoseGonzalez, ah yes, forgot about that. You can still format the double to three decimals places though, and cut the last one off.

Comment: It's a good idea, but if the number is for example, 1990,349999 the result would be 1990,35 instead of 34.

Comment: @JoseGonzalez, indeed. I see. Maybe this time my answer is correct? :)